# Push an array to an array of the same type in Vue3 typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, axios, infinite-scroll, vue3-carousel

I have an array of Obj1. In a project vue 3+ts , after clicking the button "load more", i call via axios the backend service and retrive  an array of the same type. I want to append this rows to the previous array, but it is not working :

this.Array1.push(response.data)

If i add 1 item at the time, the Array1 gets updated:

this.Array1.push(response.data[0])

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question that this code works:

```
this.Array1.push(response.data.results[0])
```

Indicates that `response.data.results` is the array you want to work with. If you want to push that entire array in, you can simply use the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals):

```
this.Array1.push(...response.data.results)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just with this.Array1.push(...response.data) :) , i wasn't using the ES6 spread operator

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing different values. response.data.results is an array, while response.data is a json data with an array.

So, you might want to just do:

`this.Array1 = response.data.results`